# How to override call_wrapper method of Spyne in Django 1.9?

Tags: django, python-2.7, spyne

I am using Django 1.9 to expose SOAP 1.1 API with Spyne version 2.12.16

I need to implement logging for every request XML and response XML in my platform.

Django urls.py is

```
url(r'^your_data/', DjangoView.as_view(
        name="YourDataService",
        services=[YourDataService],
        tns='http://127.0.0.1:8000/',
        in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
        out_protocol=Soap11()))
```

views.py:

```
from spyne.decorator import rpc
from spyne.model.primitive import String, AnyDict
from spyne.service import ServiceBase

class YourDataService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(String, String, String, _returns=AnyDict)
    def call_this_method(self, a, b, c):
        return {'aa': 'OK','bb': 'Great','cc': 'Perfect'}
```

I read somewhere, overriding call_wrapper method of Spyne ServiceBase class can log request and response XML data for that service.
But implementing the same resulted in weird logging etc issues:

```
class ServiceBaseAbstract(ServiceBase):
    def call_wrapper(cls, ctx):
        try:
            return ctx.service_class.call_wrapper(ctx)
        except Exception as err:
            print err
```

It gives an error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "spyne.application.server"
```

API works fine without overriding call_wrapper.

I am really confused and can't find a way out of this. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning, and it doesn't come from Spyne but comes from Python's logging infrastructure. You need to configure Python logging to see *any* log messages.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding `call_wrapper` is to alter the way exceptions are handled / logged by Spyne.

Instead, you should configure the python logging library to display DEBUG-level messages and also enable protocol debug logging for Spyne.

```
logging.getLogger('').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)        
logging.getLogger('spyne.protocol.xml').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: I had logger issues while overriding ServiceBase class `from spyne.service import ServiceBase`. Instead, I have to override from Application Class `from spyne.application import Application` to make it work, which looks like this

`try: ctx_call_wrapper_res = super(MyApplication, self).call_wrapper(ctx)
except Exception, e: pass  # custom code`